# Avoid overwriting randomly generated index in an array

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, overwrite

How do you avoid overwriting an array if a number is randomly generated twice?

I am creating a simple javaFX program where a user can create or search for an account. The account details need to be stored at a random position within the array. My biggest challenge is not knowing how to prevent my program from overwriting an element at an index position that has already been filled.

```
   SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
   int randomNum;
   String label;
    
    
   String [] name = new String[5];


   public void create(ActionEvent event)
   {

        randomNum = rand.nextInt(5);
        
        nameText = nameField.getText();
        name[randomNum] = nameText;
        
        label = "User created sucessfully at position " + randomNum;
        
    }
```

My other concern with the code is the new array I create for a search because the index for each element will change because all `null` elements are removed to prevent a `nullpointerexception`.

```
public void search(ActionEvent event)
{
    int count = 0;
    
    
    nameText = nameField.getText();
    
    name = Arrays.stream(name)
                 .filter(s -> (s != null && s.length() > 0))
                 .toArray(String[]::new);
    
    
    boolean contains = Arrays.stream(name).anyMatch(nameText::equals);
    
    
    if(contains == true)
    {
        while(!name[count].equals(nameText))
        {
            count++;
        }
        
        label = "User " + nameText + " is registered and is " + age[count];
        nameField.setText("");
        displayLabel.setText(label);
    }
    else
    {
        label = "User " + nameText + " is not registered.";
        nameField.setText("");
        displayLabel.setText(label);
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: `do randomNum = rand.nextInt(5); while(name[randomNum] != null);` But how do you prevent the `create` method from being executed more than five times?

Comment: looks basically unrelated to javafx - first get your logic right without ui (write and provide a [mcve], only after having succeeded add fx to the mix.

Comment: The problem with ```while(name[randomNum] != null);``` is that all values of the array are null so the loop will never begin.

Comment: @Holger While that will obviously work in practice, writing a loop that can iterate an arbitrary number of times (even if only one element of the array has been set) bothers me....

Comment: @JM It's a `do ... while` loop. It always executes at least once.

Comment: @James_D I understand your concern but I don’t think that it is relevant for an array of five elements. I do not even understand the OP’s requirement to store at a random position. The position has no recognizable relevance in the posted code…

Comment: Why use random positions in an array?  Collections.shuffle() will randomize a list when you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the unused indexes and use those:

```
SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
String label;


String [] name = new String[5];
List<Integer> unusedIndexes = new ArrayList<>();
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < name.length; i++) {
        unusedIndexes.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
}


public void create(ActionEvent event) {

    if (unusedIndexes.isEmpty()) {
        // handle situation where no more slots are available
        return ;
    }

    int randomNum = unusedIndexes.remove(rand.nextInt(unusedIndexes.size())).intValue();
    
    nameText = nameField.getText();
    name[randomNum] = nameText;
    
    label = "User created sucessfully at position " + randomNum;
    
 }
```

For the search, just search for the matching index. There's no need to remove null items first (`s.equals(null)` just returns `false`):

```
public void search(ActionEvent event) {

    nameText = nameField.getText();
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < name.length && index < 0; i++) {
        if (nameText.equals(name[i])) {
            index = i;
        }
    }        
    
    if(index >= 0) {      
        label = "User " + nameText + " is registered and is " + age[index];
        nameField.setText("");
        displayLabel.setText(label);
    } else {
        label = "User " + nameText + " is not registered.";
        nameField.setText("");
        displayLabel.setText(label);
    }        
}
```

---

Note it may be easier to implement this with a `List` instead of an array, e.g.

```
SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
String label;


List<String> name = new ArrayList<>();

public void create(ActionEvent event) {

    int randomNum = rand.nextInt(name.size()+1);
    
    nameText = nameField.getText();
    name.add(randomNum, nameText);
    
    label = "User created sucessfully at position " + randomNum;
    
 }

 public void search(ActionEvent event) {

     nameText = nameField.getText();
     int index = name.indexOf(nameText);
    
     if (index >= 0) {      
         label = "User " + nameText + " is registered and is " + age.get(index);
         nameField.setText("");
         displayLabel.setText(label);
     } else {
         label = "User " + nameText + " is not registered.";
         nameField.setText("");
         displayLabel.setText(label);
     }        
 }
```

Comment: _I'm relatively new to Java and I don't get that_ then work through a tutorial on java language basics until you do (or have a concrete question to post - along with a [mcve] demonstrating what you tried and what didn't work as expected) - see the java tag wiki for referenced

Comment: @JM I honestly don't know how to describe that. It just does what the code says it does. `List<Integer> unusedIndexes = new ArrayList<>();` creates a  new list of integers. The loop adds the integers 0 through 4 (inclusive) to the list. So at the end you have a list containing the integers 0...4 (i.e. the indexes of the array, none of which have been used yet).

Comment: I read it wrong - I understand it. Cheers man, thank you.